# Netlogo: subtracting previously diffused values

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to subtract previously diffused values?

I have a land-use model where residential use (yellow patches) diffuses its land value with the diffuse primitive:

```
diffuse land-value 1
```

In the first image below, land value is represented as white tones, the brighter the tone, the higher the land value. Residential use sometimes abandons the patch, but their land value influence stays (second image). Is there a way that, when the land use disappears, the value it previously diffused to all patches be subtracted and also disappear?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think that's almost impossible. If in your model is only one residential, you could reset the land-value to its setup values. But when you have a model with multiple residentials,  their effects on the land-value will intertwine.
You could perhaps include a procedure, that lets the patches reduce the land-value, so that some time, after the resident has left, its influence disappears. But that depends on the purpose of your model, if you want to include that :)

Comment: I think you would have to spawn an 'invisible' house with a negative value. But it depends on when and how often you call this diffuse function.

Comment: @Jumboman: I have tried a negative number for the diffuse primitive but NetLogo does not accept it. The diffuse function is called at every tick, so it accumulates over time, but I can try to use it only once when the new land use is created

Comment: @Lena: The intertwining you talk about is the main challenge. I´m thinking about the following procedure: besides diffusing a value to other patches, land use also passes information about their ID. In this manner, the model checks at each tick what land uses have disappeared, detect by ID the values they diffused, and subtract it from all the patches of the world. Could this be done?

Comment: Is it required that you diffuse on multiple ticks after the establishment of the residential patches? Or are you more using diffuse to represent the `land-value` diminishing with distance from a residential patch? I'm wondering if you could represent that diffusion with some function of distance, which would simplify the problem.

Comment: Javier, following the suggestion by @LukeC in the comment above, I came up with a working solution of how this would work. So let us know if that kind of framing (diffusion as function of distance) is good for you. Also, Luke, this comment might be a heads up for Javier but perhaps you should leave an answer in case, given that the approach was an idea of yours :)

Comment: @Matteo - Thank you for the heads-up, but please have at it! I will gladly avoid doing math if you already have a working idea :D

Comment: @LukeC Ok, I attempted a reply, feel free to suggest anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following comments under the question and following Luke's suggestion of framing the diffusion of `land-value` as a function of distance instead of a recurring `diffuse`, I have set up the following solution (in point 1).

Below (in point 2), you find a possible approach (not fully coded, but sketched-out enough) for addressing the issue if you want to stick to `diffuse`.

### 1 - Approach with function of distance

What happens here is that, when a patch gains residential status (`to create-residence`), all other patches in a certain radius calculate how much spill-over land-value they get based on the residential value of the new residential patch and on how much it is distant (`to-report diffused-value`).

The advantage of this approach is that this calculation is fully replicable at any moment because it is based on two constants: the distance between patches and the initial residential value of the patch in question (for which I created the patches-own `own-residential-value`, distinct from the general `land-value`).

For this reason, when a patch loses residential use (`to dismantle-residence`) it is possible to perform the same calculation but, instead of having patches add `diffused-value` to their `land-value`, they will subtract it.

I think the code I place below best illustrates its functionality if you create the `create-residence` and `dismantle-residence` buttons in the Interface, and play with them to see how overlapping land-values add and subtract in the View.

```
globals [
 ; Agentsets for patches.
 residence
 non-residence
]

patches-own [
  land-value
  own-residential-value
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set non-residence (patch-set patches)
  set residence (patch-set)
end

to create-residence
  let new-res one-of non-residence

  ask new-res [
   set non-residence (patch-set other non-residence)
   set residence (patch-set self residence)

   set own-residential-value (random 10) + 1
   set land-value (land-value + own-residential-value)
   set pcolor yellow

   diffuse-value
  ]

  update-colours
end

to diffuse-value
  ask other patches in-radius 10 [
   set land-value (land-value + diffused-value)
  ]
end

to dismantle-residence
  let target one-of residence

  ask target [
   set residence (patch-set other residence)
   set non-residence (patch-set self non-residence)

   ; As opposed to 'to create-residence', where 'diffuse-value' is at the end of this block of commands,
   ; here 'subtract-value' has to be placed before the patch updates its 'own-residential-value' to 0,
   ; because that value is needed to calculate 'diffused-value'.
   subtract-value

   set land-value (land-value - own-residential-value)
   set own-residential-value 0
  ]

  update-colours
end

to subtract-value
  ask other patches in-radius 10 [
   set land-value (land-value - diffused-value)
  ]
end

to-report diffused-value
  ; Here, 'myself' is the new residential patch (as 'new-res' in 'to create-residence') or
  ; the new non-residential patch (as 'target' in 'to dismantle-residence').
  let d distance myself
  let v [own-residential-value] of myself

  report v * (0.9 / d) ; Just an arbitrary function of value and distance.
end

to update-colours
  ask non-residence [
    set pcolor scale-color white land-value 0 15
  ]
end
```

### 2 - Approach if sticking to `diffuse`

I have though of an approach for this case too, but I also want to understand if `diffuse` really is what you want to use.

As we know, `diffuse` is a [zero-sum game](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#diffuse): what is diffused by a patch is also lost by a patch.

Therefore, I imagine you will not be just using `diffuse land-value 1`, because in that case `land-value` of the residential patch will be 0 after one tick, will very slightly recover on the subsequent tick, and will then progressively approach 0 from the third tick on.

For example, the following code gives the results as in the table below:

```
patches-own [
  land-value
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  
  ask patch 0 0 [set land-value 50]
end

to go
  diffuse land-value 1
  tick
end
```

[image]

I doubt this is anything you are interested in replicating, so I assume the approach would be something like:

```
patches-own [
  land-value
  temp
]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  
  ask patch 0 0 [set land-value 50]
end

to go
  diffuse-value
  tick
end

to diffuse-value
  ask patches [
   set temp land-value 
  ]
  
  diffuse land-value 1
  
  ask patches [
   set land-value (land-value + temp) 
  ]
end
```

However, I think that even in this case `diffuse` seems to be not fit for representing a residential value spreading to near-by areas. By using the code above, in fact, the result is the following:

[image]

The table above shows that, in 15 ticks, the patch which should be the one diffusing some value in the area experienced a 93593% increase (no, I didn't forget any decimal point!) in its land value. I know of course this might be mitigated with some formula, but I think it shows the *tendency* of `diffuse` in this case: to create an escalating positive feedback between patches, so that a small residential value grows without control.

I'm not the expert of residential values here, but I felt these results (from both the former and the latter use of `diffuse`) were worth pointing out from a NetLogo perspective.

**That said**, if the idea is to stick to `diffuse`...

```
patches-own [
 land-value
 own-residential-value
 residential-start
 temp
]

to setup
 ; Some code.
end

to go
 ; Some code.
end


to create-residence   ; Executed by the observer. This procedure cannot be executed by the patch becoming residence because it contains 'diffuse'.
 
 let target ; <- Identify here the patch that needs to become residence.
 
 ask target [
  ; Set 'own-residential-value' to something.
  set land-value (land-value + own-residential-value)
  set residential-start ticks
 ]

 ; Have some code here that uses 'diffuse own-residential-value'.

end


to dismantle-residence   ; Executed by the observer. This procedure cannot be executed by the patch being dismantled because it contains 'diffuse'.

 ask patches [set temp 0] ; This is crucial in order to avoid any overlap among patches when using 'diffuse'.
 
 let target ; <- Identify here the patch that needs to be dismantled.
 let time-as-residence (ticks - [residential-start] of target)
  
 ask target [
   set temp own-residential-value 
  ]
  
 repeat time-as-residence [
  ; Insert here the exact same code that
  ; was used for using 'diffuse' but
  ; diffusing the 'temp' variable instead
  ; (e.g. 'diffuse temp 1').
 ]

 ask patches with [temp > 0] [
  set land-value (land-value - temp)
 ]
end
```

What happens above is that, whenever a patch loses residential use, the program performs exactly the same number of `diffuse` operations as it performed when actually diffusing `land-value` during the residential life of the patch at stake, but on `temp` instead of `land-value`. This way, all the surrounding patches will store in `temp` the same value they gained over time from the patch being dismantled - so they can subtract this value from their current `land-value`.

The success of this approach depends on the `ask patches [set temp 0]` statement: given that `diffuse` operates on each patch, by setting all `temp` to 0 and then doing `ask target [set temp own-residential-value]` we make sure that we only reproduce the pattern of value-diffusion that can be attributed to the patch being dismantled - avoiding any overlap that might have occurred over time, when patches may have gathered (and then re-diffused) value from other residential patches.

(This is based on the assumption that you use `diffuse` at every tick, as you said in a comment to the question. Even if that ceases to be the case, it will be easy to set `time-as-residence` in an alternative way according to the number of times that `diffuse` took place since a particular patch became residential)

**Potential problem** This is something that you will have to untangle yourself, but consider that there remains a possible issue: you have to decide whether you want to diffuse `own-residential-value` or `land-value`, with both options presenting some problem.

- Diffusing `own-residential-value` seems intuitive to me, since that is the added value; however, this means that the diffused value would go into `own-residential-value` of the other patches (and not into their `land-value`) even if they really do not have any residential value of their own, which will create the need for extra computation (a possible option could be to rename `own-residential-value` to something more appropriate, like `residential-value`, and create a further `tot-value` patches-own variable that is updated at every tick as `set tot-value land-value + residential-value`).
- On the other hand, diffusing `land-value` would be more straightforward in terms of coding (`land-value` would just propagate to other patches' `land-value`) but seems less precise based on what I can understand, given residential patches would be propagating `land-value` which often will not be just the new residential value that they bring, but also the result of that positive feedback discussed before, building on other patches' residential values.

### Conclusions

While I'm quite confident that the second approach is viable and technically good, I definitely prefer the first based on the doubts that I expressed over the use of `diffuse` for this particular goal (at least based on the understanding I have of your intentions, which I might not understand fully) - and the feeling that a function of distance looks like a neat approach to diffusion of value in this scenario.