# How to create a diffuse function without the diffuse primitive?

Tags: netlogo

I am creating a model for principles in a biological space.  I am struggling to "control" the diffuse primitive.  By control, I don't necessarily mean they need to be exact values, I just need them within a predictable range.  The values diffusing are getting incredibly small and the patch property eventually decays. The original patch, that first diffused to the eight around it, is being diffused to by its neighbors, decreasing its original property.

I am attempting to use the uphill function to cause turtles to pull towards these patches, so I need them to keep their property without decaying.

I am attempting to create my own diffuse function, updating the values of patch neighbors until a certain point, but am struggling to make it work.  Any references or tips on primitives' I should explore?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are calling diffuse on all patches every tick, causing your original values to dissipate too quickly, correct? Have you tried only calling diffuse every X ticks?

Comment: I may be wrong but it seems to me that you might want to use something that is different from `diffuse`. Maybe you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68946407/12391423), especially the `Approach with funcion of distance` section. That answer is quite long and you don't need it all, but that part might give you inspiration. If you need an answer that is more taylored to your case, edit your question to illustrate your case and what you have

Comment: Thank you @Matteo !  I am going to attempt to implement the distance function instead.  From my understanding of the reference, it should give us some control of the "diffused" property regardless of the runtime.  I will update my question after I have tried this!

Comment: Thank you @Jumboman !  I have now tried only calling diffuse every X tick and it definitely helped.  That said, we run the model with varying lengths of time depending on other variables in the model, so it is difficult to determine what I should change X to depending on the model's state.  I am going to try a different direction with the distance function, but I appreciate your help!